# how can i get current phone timezone in windowsphone

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7

Windows phone user can set timezone or set automatically option on settings->datetime section. I want to get this timezone from my app

How can i do that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
    TimeZoneInfo localZone = TimeZoneInfo.Local;
string text = String.Format("{0}{1}:{2:00} ({3})",(localZone.BaseUtcOffset >= TimeSpan.Zero) ? "" : "-", Math.Abs(localZone.BaseUtcOffset.Hours),
                          Math.Abs(localZone.BaseUtcOffset.Minutes),TimeZoneInfo.Local.DisplayName);
```

Maybe this helps. It assembles the TZ info into a string.

Comment: Or maybe `localzone.StandardName` might help